# Display sub menus as separate lists

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu

I need to change the way of rendering menu in WordPress - I guess I should write my own walker class but I'm not sure how to bite it. What I'd like to achieve is to render each level of menu as separate div. So we have pretty standard wp menu:

```
<ul class="dropmenu main-menu" id="menu-some-stupid-name">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-83" id="menu-item-83">
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/flext/contact/">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-85" id="menu-item-85">
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/flext/blog/">Blog</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu"> 
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99" id="menu-item-99"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/flext/blog/">Blog</a></li>  
        </ul>
   </li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-86" id="menu-item-86"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/flext/">Home</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">  
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-101" id="menu-item-101"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/flext/">Home</a></li>   
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-102" id="menu-item-102"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/flext/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I'd like to achieve is this:

```
   <ul class="dropmenu main-menu" id="menu-some-stupid-name">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-83" id="menu-item-83"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/flext/contact/">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-85" id="menu-item-85"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/flext/blog/">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-86" id="menu-item-86"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/flext/">Home</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="sub-menu child-menu-item-85"> 
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99" id="menu-item-99"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/flext/blog/">Blog</a></li>  
    </ul>

    <ul class="sub-menu child-menu-item-86">  
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-101" id="menu-item-101"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/flext/">Home</a></li>   
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-102" id="menu-item-102"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/flext/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Is it possible to achieve with custom Walker_Nav_Menu class? I'd really appreciate any ideas. Thanks

Comment: IMO, your best bite is take any of the examples you find in this [very Stack](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Walker_Nav_Menu) and poke with it, and then come back and [improve your Question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to not change anything in walker class and "parse" the menu with jQuery, clone each children and append to "menu" container which gives me the result I was looking for. The only thing missing is how to pass ID of menu element which has childrens to start_lvl function.

Thanks